# How to implement grouped filters filtered by roles?

Tags: views

Is it possible to make exposed grouped filters where some filters are only available for certain roles?

Answer (score 0):

Clone the view you already have into an additional views display, add the exposed grouped filters to that cloned views display, and then limited that additional views display to only those "certain roles".

Comment: So if I get it right, that means that if a user has multiple roles, then he cannot see it in 1 view, but needs multiple views all with different filters?

That's what I was afraid of...
I have 10 different roles, but everyone can have multiple ones of these roles, so there are 2^10 possibilities, so that would mean I'd have to make 1024 different views? Well, that doesn't seem like a possibility to me :( But I was already afraid that this would have been the answer